# undefined control sequence after `\paragraph`

Tags: paragraphs

I try to use `\paragraph{xx}`, but I get the error (in the next line with text, after the `\paragraph`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<everypar> ...ubpenalty \@M \begingroup \@svsechd
\endgroup \unskip \@tempsk...
```

(This is with `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`.
This is using the [Interspeech 2020 template](http://www.interspeech2020.org/Authors/Author_Resources/).
From a brief look in `INTERSPEECH2020.sty`,
it does some definitions like `\def\@sect` in there.
Not sure if anything of that is relevant.)

Why? What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: There's almost no way to tell what's going on here without more information.  `\paragraph{}` itself is not the problem, and the error is probably before that.

Comment: How can I find out what the error is? I thought I posted all relevant parts of the error message. Or is there some verbose flag to output an extended stack trace of the error?

Comment: it is almost always best to include a complete small document that shows the error, then people can debug it and test answers.

Comment: Yes, I know. But so you say it's really not possible to get any information out of the error message, and the best way is for others to just try around? (I will try to reduce it later to sth I can put here. But that will cost me lots of time. I was really hoping that there is some way around that, by providing error information here. I was hoping for some well-known error. But at least I get from the response that this does not really seem to be some well-known problem...)

Comment: you can get the equivalent of a full stack trace (put `\errorcontextlines=1000`) but for an undefined command it won't tell you a lot as it will just fail to show the command definition, really need a full example then look at it and determine what the package author's intention was and suggesting a fix.

Comment: The package says you should not use more that three levels of sectioning, and does not define a `\paragraph` level. This is indirectly the source of the problem. One solution would be to simply fake your own `\paragraph` command like this: `\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{{\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\normalfont\bfseries#1\quad}}`. This doesn't make a formal sectioning level and won't produce the error. Whether using this will fit the rules of the template is debatable, however.

Comment: It may help to think of the names of the sectioning levels as if they came from a legal code: "Part III, Chapter 4, Section 5, Subsection i, Sub-subsection J, Paragraph 21, Sub-paragraph (a) says that you are not allowed to ...". The sectioning names are arbitrary. A "paragraph", as a block of text, can appear at any level.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments and the answer. I don't really need it to formally define a (subsubsub)section, I'm totally fine with your redefinitions (actually that was my workaround already after writing this question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer, I think, is that you shouldn't use `\paragraph` at all. The style file you are working with defines suitable commands only for `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection`, and modifies some internal LaTeX commands so that they cannot cope without error with run-in headings, as paragraph normally is. It's rather messy, but it presumably copes with everything the organisers want it to, and the fact it *doesn't* cope with `\paragraph` tells its own story.

Perhaps, since you are using a style file to get the formatting the organisers want, you should ... respect their wishes in that regard. If you just want some bold text, you could simply

```
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\noindent\textbf{#1}\quad}
```

And make sure not to leave a blank line before the actual text of the paragraph.

(If you feel strongly, there's an email contact in the style file, to which you can make representations!)